# What is a blob type in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm reading the inline API docs for a PHP function and I can't make sense of the `_blob_` type it is looking for as part of the `Data` key that is supposed to contain a raw email. I have a raw email string, but have no idea how to convert it to a `blob` per the API below. I've never heard of a `blob` referenced outside of the context of databases.

I tried passing a string instead of a `blob` but it didn't work.

Google is of no help on this.

```
/**
         * Method: send_raw_email()
         *      Sends an email message, with header and content specified by the client. The SendRawEmail action is
         *      useful for sending multipart MIME emails, with attachments or inline content.
         *
         *      The raw text of the message must comply with Internet email standards; otherwise, the message
         *      cannot be sent.
         *
         * Access:
         *      public
         *
         * Parameters:
         *      $raw_message - _ComplexType_ (Required) The raw text of the message. The client is responsible for ensuring the following: Message must contain a header and a body, separated by a blank line.; All required header fields must be present.; Each part of a multipart MIME message must be formatted properly.; MIME content types must be among those supported by Amazon SES. Refer to the Amazon SES Developer Guide for more details. ; Content must be base64-encoded, if MIME requires it.. A required ComplexType is a set of key-value pairs which must be set by passing an associative array with certain entries as keys. See below for a list.
         *      $opt - _array_ (Optional) An associative array of parameters that can have the keys listed in the following section.
         *
         * Keys for the $raw_message parameter:
         *      Data - _blob_ (Required) The raw data of the message. The client must ensure that the message format complies with Internet email standards surrounding email header fields, MIME types, MIME encoding, and base64 encoding (if necessary).
         *
         * Keys for the $opt parameter:
         *      Source - _string_ (Optional) The sender's email address.
         *      Destinations - _string_|_array_ (Optional) A list of destinations for the message. Pass a string for a single value, or an indexed array for multiple values.
         *      returnCurlHandle - _boolean_ (Optional) A private toggle specifying that the cURL handle be returned rather than actually completing the request. This toggle is useful for manually managed batch requests.
         *
         * Returns:
         *      _CFResponse_ A <CFResponse> object containing a parsed HTTP response.
         */
        public function send_raw_email($raw_message, $opt = null)
        {
                if (!$opt) $opt = array();

                // Optional parameter
                if (isset($opt['Destinations']))
                {
                        $opt = array_merge($opt, CFComplexType::map(array(
                                'Destinations' => (is_array($opt['Destinations']) ? $opt['Destinations'] : array($opt['Destinations']))
                        ), 'member'));
                        unset($opt['Destinations']);
                }

                // Required parameter
                $opt = array_merge($opt, CFComplexType::map(array(
                        'RawMessage' => (is_array($raw_message) ? $raw_message : array($raw_message))
                ), 'member'));

                return $this->authenticate('SendRawEmail', $opt, $this->hostname, 3);
        }
}
```

Comment: It's not a PHP type. I think they're just using that term to mean a string that contains raw binary data.

Comment: I originally thought that, too. But it's not working so I'm not sure what to think. I'm not getting any errors so not sure what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be using ColdFusion, I think it's a CF concept.

Comment: What isn't working? Show how you're calling the function.

Comment: The email isn't getting sent. The call is simple: `$status = $mailer->send_raw_email(array( 'Data' => $message['body']), array( Destinations => $destination['ToAddresses'], Source => $source) );`

Comment: Have you tried reading the published documentation? Maybe it has examples.

Comment: Well, I figured out that the email gets delivered if through if I base64_encode the string (even though amazon documentation said the sdk will take care of encoding it). However, the actual raw email with the headers shows up in the person's inbox. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Well, I was able to fix it up. The software wasn't generating valid raw email like I thought. Had to massage it a little. Still had to base64_encode the message, as well.